# ANOVA. Let α β γ δ be regressors. If you discuss the interaction α*β*γ, can you discuss β*γ*δ too?

Tags: regression, anova, interaction, treatment-effect

I've been taught that if you discuss an interaction of the regressors α and β, then you can't discuss the simple effects (α alone and β alone).

I guess you can't even discuss αβ if you discussed αβγ.

I wondered that maybe the rule is that in general you can't discuss different interactions if they share any subset of regressors. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were taught wrong. You can, and should, interpret the main effects; they are the effects if the other variables are 0. If you appropriately centered your variables, then that is very useful information.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does it mean to center one's variables? It might be that I already do it but I don't know it's called that way.

Comment: For categorical variables you make sure that one outcome category is 0. For continuous variables you make sure that the value 0 represents a reasonable value with the range of the data. For example, if you have years of education in the US educational system you would subtract 12 to make the value 0 represent the high school graduates. Alternatively, some subtract the mean.